# Using a variable or string as a file name for importing data using query tables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import a lot of text files with numerical names into a separate worksheets.

The loop to create the worksheets works fine

```
Dim i as integer 'initial file name
Dim k as integer 'final file name
i = Cells(3, 3).Value
k = Cells(5, 3).Value

Do while i <= k
    Worksheets.Add.Name = i
    i = i +5
Loop
```

and for importing specific individual files, this line also seems to work fine (when including  the .FileNames .RowNumbers. RefreshPeriod etc. commands):

```
With Activesheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\temp\load_excel\15.txt" _, Destination:=Range ("$A$1"))
```

I would like to replace the "TEXT;C:\temp\load_excel\15.txt" with something more that allows me to use two different variables to change the files being imported:

```
Dim Folder As String
Dim File As String
Dim DQ as String

DQ = """" 'double quotation marks
Folder = Cells(14, 2).Value 'cell which states C:\temp\load_excel\
File = DQ & "TEXT;" & Folder & i & ".txt" & DQ
'for i = 15 this gives "TEXT;C:\temp\load_excel\15.txt"
```

Is there a way to incorporate the two so I can have a loop like this?

```
Do while i <=k
    Worksheets.Add.Name = i
    Activesheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= File _, Destination:=Range ("$A$1"))
    i = i +5
Loop
```

As far as I can see, this should work, but when I try and run it I get a Run-time error '1004': Application or object-defined error. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here is exact code being used

```
Sub ImportPLEtextFiles()

Dim i As Integer ''initial file name
Dim k As Integer ''final file name
Dim DQ As String '' Double quotation marks
Dim Folder As String
Dim File As String

i = Cells(3, 3).Value
k = Cells(5, 3).Value
DQ = """"
Folder = Cells(14, 2).Value
File = DQ & Folder & i & ".txt" & DQ

Do While i <= k
Worksheets.Add.Name = i

File = DQ & "TEXT;" & Folder & i & ".txt" & DQ

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=File _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


i = i + 5
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact code? This should work, but there are some typos in the example Loop, the code doesn't even compile, and probably you don't need the DQ at start and end of File variable

Comment: Agreed regarding the double quotes...  Not sure why you would want to include those.

Comment: @user3964075  and @bp_ exact code posted. I assumed that the string File would need **"** marks so that it would be treated as plain text as `"TEXT;C:\temp\load_excel\15.txt"` was when referenced directly

Comment: Did you try it without DQ? The DQ's in `"TEXT;C:\temp\load_excel\15.txt"` just indicate that this is a `string` constant.

Comment: @user3964075 

Great thank you! It works fine now I've removed the double quotes, thank you for explaining that. Would you like to officially submit an answer so I can confirm it here on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this inside your loop.

```
File = "TEXT;" & Cells(14, 2).Value & i & ".txt"
    With Sheets(i).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        File, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```